# Solve DOE system with polar coordinates?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates

I am studying for a exam and one of model questions is solve a DOE system using polar coordinates. I've research and didn't find any reference about this subject.

System in question is

$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
x'= (1-x^2-y^2)x - y & \\ 
y'= x+(1-x^2-y^2)y& 
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

I know that I can do $1-x^2-y^2 = 1-(x^2+y^2)=1-r^2$. I know, too, that solutions are as $c_{1}X_{1}e^{\lambda_{1} x}+c_{2}X_{2}e^{\lambda_{2} x}+...$, where $X_{n}$ are eigenvectors and $\lambda_{n}$ are eigenvalues. So:

$$
p(x)=
det\begin{bmatrix}
1-r^2-\lambda & -1 \\ 
1 & 1-r^2-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}
=(1-r^2-\lambda)^{2}+1
=0
$$

I will have a biquadratic equation with many lambda equations. Am I right or I got lost?

Comment: With enough work, you can solve it in that way, but I shudder at the thought. However, if you just make the substitutions $x = r\cos \theta, y = r\sin \theta$, into the two equations and look at them without any more simplification than what you have already described and using the product rule on the LH sides, a visual inspection should reveal what $r'$ and $\theta'$ are equal to.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
x=\rho \cos(\theta)  \rightarrow x' =\rho'\cos(\theta) -\rho \sin(\theta) \theta' & \\ 
y=\rho \cos(\theta) \rightarrow y' =\rho'\sin(\theta) +\rho \cos(\theta) \theta' & 
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
x'= (1-x^2-y^2)x - y = \rho'\cos(\theta) -\rho \sin(\theta) \theta' = (1-\rho^2)\rho \cos(\theta) - \rho \sin(\theta) & \\ 
y'= (1-x^2-y^2)y + x = \rho'\sin(\theta) +\rho \cos(\theta) \theta' = (1-\rho^2)\rho \sin(\theta) + \rho \cos(\theta) & 
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
\rho'\cos(\theta) -\rho \sin(\theta) \theta' = (1-\rho^2)\rho \cos(\theta) - \rho \sin(\theta) & \\ 
\rho'\sin(\theta) +\rho \cos(\theta) \theta' = (1-\rho^2)\rho \sin(\theta) + \rho \cos(\theta) & 
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
First equation multiplied by $\cos(\theta)$ + second equation multiplied by $\sin(\theta)$

Second equation multiplied by $\cos(\theta)$ - first equation multiplied by $\sin(\theta)$

$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
\rho' = (1-\rho^2)\rho & \\ 
\theta' = 1 & 
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
I let you continue and find $\rho(t)$ and $\theta(t)$.