# Showing existence of periodic orbit using Poincaré-Bendixson theorem

Tags: dynamical-systems

> Show that $\dot x = x-y-x(x^2+y^2)$,
> $\dot y=y+x-y(x^2+y^2)$
> has at least one periodic orbit.

I calculated the equilibrium point which came out to be only the origin.

I converted the given system into polar coordinates:
$\dot r=r-r^3$
$\dot \theta=1$

Then I get that
$\dot r \gt0$  provided $r\lt1$
$\dot r \lt0$  provided $r\gt1$

So we get that $r=1$ is a stable limit cycle in this case, but we are not getting any annular region. So can I take the annular region to be the region enclosed by $r=\frac{1}{2}$ and $r=1$ or say, $r=1$ and $r=2$ ?

Comment: Why would you need Poincaré–Bendixson if you already know a periodic solution *explicitly*?!

Comment: Ooh! Right. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4330898/poincare-map-for-polar-ode for the same system. Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3230991/finding-alpha-and-omega-limit-set, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419147/solve-doe-system-with-polar-coordinates, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3586968/conversion-of-ode-system-to-polar

Comment: Split the difference and use both, $\frac12\le r\le 2$.